# permissions for location 3G

Tags: android, location

what is the difference between these two permissions?

```
Allows an application to access coarse
Allows an application to access fine
```

according to the documentation of android allows an application to access coarse is used for wifi and Allows an application to access fine for GPS but for 3G localitation, which should I use?

Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3G is from the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` , and needs the permission "coarse", according to [the manual](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html)

> In order to receive location updates from NETWORK_PROVIDER or
>   GPS_PROVIDER, you must request user permission by declaring either the
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission,
>   respectively

(mind the word "respectively" here :)  )